# How to stream MP4/AVI files directly in browser?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

Is there any streaming server or solution preferably open-source solution exist for streaming MP4/AVI directly to browser. I know it is possible to stream, when video converted to **flv**.
But, my restriction is I couldn't modify those MP4/AVI files.

Comment: What do you mean by MP4/AVI files, MP4 files in an AVI container?

Comment: both mp4 standalone plus in avi container. If it possible to play other avi format that would add value to it.

Comment: Flash Player >= 10 (IIRC) can play MP4 files. Apart from that, I think you are out of luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stream H.264 encoded videos you may want to have a look at this site: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/WikiStart

Never tested it but it has some nice features like `Timeshifting seek` which enables your viewers to immediately jump to any point in the video.

Here is a demo using it and it's quiete nice: http://h264-demo.code-shop.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround but Ustream has worked for me before.